# UMBRACO - content is missing after helper - why?

Tags: .net, content-management-system, umbraco

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage<ContentModels.Home>
@using ContentModels = Umbraco.Web.PublishedContentModels;
@{
    Layout = "master.cshtml";
}

<p>I can see it on a page</p>

@CurrentPage.GetGridHtml("ajs");

<p>this part is missing</p>
```

why? Can you point me to the part of docs that explain that?

Comment: Have you tried without the trailing semi-colon?

Comment: Just tried it - no effect

Comment: Got some detail -there is a AngularJS in grid, that come with macro. If I put simple heading - everything is ok

Comment: it's all my fault. Problem was in closing tag in angular script. Saw it only in VSCODE, not in embbeded umbraco editor